# What language did Joseph speak in Egypt?

Tags: genesis, language, joseph

What language did Joseph speak in Egypt? How did he learn it? Was there a common language like Aramaic?

In Genesis 39 part of his ability to find favor must have been the ability to communicate accurately. Similarly, he is shown here as communicating fluently with the Egyptians:

> Genesis 40:6-8: And Joseph came in unto them in the morning, and looked upon them, and, behold, they were sad. And *he asked Pharaoh's officers* that were with him in the ward of his lord's house, *saying*, Wherefore look ye so sadly to day? And *they said unto him*, We have dreamed a dream, and there is no interpreter of it. And *Joseph said unto them*, Do not interpretations belong to God? tell me them, I pray you.

Comment: This question offers no opportunity for exegesis.  It properly belongs in a history or religion forum.  Vote to close.

Comment: I don't quite understand this question. Joseph had already been in Egypt for a number of years when this story happened. He surely could have learned Egyptian by then.

Comment: He was slave/prisoner in Egypt and/or one of its vassal states for quite a few number of years. He must have had plenty of opportunities to pick up the dominant language of the region.

Comment: Therefore, there are two pronunciations for the name of God, that of Moses and that of Aaron.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Bible places the Exodus around 1440 BCE and therefore Joseph around 1870 BCE.

To be able to speak to the pharaohs and the common Egyptian people, Joseph would have needed to speak either Egyptian or a *lingua franca* known widely enough to be helpful. The [Amarna letters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amarna_letters#Chronology) may help in this regard, although they are somewhat later, around 1350 BCE.

The Canaanite petty kings who wrote to their Egyptian overlords could not speak Egyptian, and it appears the Egyptians could not speak Canaanite, so the letters were written in Akkadian, which was the language of regional diplomacy and the earliest attested form of Semitic language. So, an important resident of Canaan would probably have known some Akkadian. His linguistic skill demonstrated almost as soon as he arrived in Egypt means we should expect Joseph to have been fluent in this language, bearing in mind that the Bible says Joseph went to Egypt while still quite young.

Assuming, then, that Joseph knew some [Akkadian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akkadian_language), he would have been able to communicate with the pharaoh and some high officials, but he would have needed to learn Egyptian in order to survive in Egypt.

Another alternative is that Joseph might have been able to use Hyksos intermediaries as interpreters, however the Bible suggests that Joseph arrived in Egypt before the putative Hyksos invasion.

Comment: Thank you. I had just been reading about the reasons for the collapse of the Akkadian culture and wondered if it might have a connection. From there the question. Now I have to be careful not to be biased and mark it as correct immediately.

Comment: FWIW, Akkadian become a lingua franca in the *late* Bronze Age.  Even the Amarna letters are not in actual Akkadian but “used Akkadian words, spelled in cuneiform, to write Canaanite” (Eva von Dassow, ‘Canaanite in Cuneiform’, JAOS 124:4; 2004).  That is, the royal scribes didn't know Akkadian In the 14th C BCE, much less the son of a Bedouin herder 500 years earlier.  During the time in which Joseph’s story is set, people of the Levant spoke a variant of proto-Semitic (Canaanite languages emerged centuries later).  Joseph's language was obviously not a concern of the biblical storytellers.

Comment: @Schuh i) FWIW I disagree about 'late Bronze Age'; ii) Akkadian used cuneiform from ~2500BCE; iii) that "the biblical storytellers" did not consider how Joseph would not have considered how Joseph was supposed to speak to the Egyptians is probably a true statement, however I was concerned with hermeneutics here, not expounding on the underlying truth of the story - you will notice I did not say what 'did' happen, but what 'would have' happened.

Comment: Well, you might want to check-out Wikipedia which dates Middle Akkadian/Babylonian as a written, diplomatic *lingua franca* in the area to the 16th C, not before.  Then we could throw in the Hyksos history and say a Canaanite boy in Egypt wouldn’t have had to learn a new language.  Good luck! :)

Comment: @Schuh I think you have probably got a few of your facts wrong, but the Hyksos idea is at least a useful one. They probably arrived in Egypt well after the time attributed to Joseph, but close enough to be worth a mention. Based on your input, I have added this. Another alternative hinted at by your earlier comment about "not a concern of the biblical storytellers" is that Joseph had no way of communicating with the Egyptians until he slowly and laboriously learnt their language - but I won't go there.

Answer (score 1):

Joseph spoke in the language what the local spoke at the time, i.e., Egyptian language.

> Genesis 39:23 The warden paid no attention to anything under Joseph's care, because **the LORD was with Joseph and gave him success in whatever he did**.

Joseph was a teenager when he arrived in Egypt. His brain was still adaptable to a new language naturally.

He was a slave and had to talkd to fellow slaves in Egypt for some years before Potiphar put him in charge of his household.

> Genesis 39:6
> So Potiphar left everything he had in Joseph's care; with Joseph in charge, he did not concern himself with anything except the food he ate.

Now, he had to learn to vocabulary to talk to an upper class of people, even to Pharaoh later on.

> Genesis 41:41 So Pharaoh said to Joseph, “**I hereby put you in charge of the whole land of Egypt**.”

I doubt that Pharaoh would put Joseph at such a high position if Joseph did not speak perfect Egyptian, that he sounded like a foreigner.

> 42Then Pharaoh took his signet ring from his finger and put it on Joseph’s finger. He dressed him in robes of fine linen and put a gold chain around his neck. 43He had him ride in a chariot as his second-in-command, and people shouted before him, “Make way c !” Thus he put him in charge of the whole land of Egypt.
>
> 44Then Pharaoh said to Joseph, “I am Pharaoh, but without your word no one will lift hand or foot in all Egypt.” 45Pharaoh gave Joseph the name **Zaphenath-Paneah** and gave him Asenath daughter of Potiphera, priest of On, to be his wife. And **Joseph went throughout the land of Egypt.**

If he didn't speak perfect Egyptian, I doubt he could command the respect of the Pharaoh and local officials.

His **Egyptian** name Zaphenath-Paneah means 'the god **speaks** and he lives'

Would you think that the Egyptian god speaks with a foreign tongue?

Joseph was a smart guy and quick to learn and the LORD was with Joseph and gave him success in whatever he did, including picking up the local language.